# How to Have image fit in card perfectly with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I'm currently trying to list out all my products on a page with cards. However, the images are causing strange gaps within my cards. I've tried adding a max-height to the images but that's made some of the images look too squashed or strange. Is there a workaround for this other than manually resizing my images?
[image]

This is an example of one product.

```css
  .products-center {
    /*have products take up 90% and center it*/
    width: 90vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1170px;

    /*better than grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);*/
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-column-gap: 1.5rem;
    grid-row-gap: 2rem;
    
  }

  .product{
    box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .img-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
  }

  .product-img {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 15rem;
    transition: var(--mainTransition);
  }
```

```html
    <div class='products-center'>
      <!-- single product -->
      <article class="product">
        <div class='img-container'>
          <img src="./images/blackberry-roll.jpg" alt="product" class='product-img'>
          <button class='bag-btn' data-id='1'>
            <i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>
            add to cart
          </button>
          
        </div>
        <h3>Blackberry Bomb</h3>
        <h4>$3/roll</h4>
      </article>

      <!-- end of single product -->
    </div>
```

Comment: The best solution would be to have all images with the exact same ratio. But you can bypass that by putting your images in a container div for which you set sizes with overflow hidden. It should do the trick, but only one part of the images with a vertical ratio would be visible of course.

Comment: As @Dexter0015 pointed out, you should start with all the images the same aspect ratio. If that is not possible, you can set a height and use `object-fit` property on the `img` element, but the image will be cropped and may not crop how you want it. Also, you should update your code with all four images so we can offer a solution.

Comment: you can also use the `object-fit` css property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example setting a `max-height` on the `img-container` and using `object-fit` on the `img`

```css
.products-center {
  /*have products take up 90% and center it*/
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  /*better than grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 1.5rem;
  grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}

.product {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* RESPONSIVE BUT SETTING A MAX-HEIGHT */
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.product-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 15rem;
  transition: var(--mainTransition);
  /* USING OBJECT FIT */
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class='products-center'>
  <!-- single product -->
  <article class="product">
    <div class='img-container'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="product" class='product-img'>
      <button class='bag-btn' data-id='1'>
            <i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>
            add to cart
          </button>

    </div>
    <h3>Blackberry Bomb</h3>
    <h4>$3/roll</h4>
  </article>

  <article class="product">
    <div class='img-container'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="product" class='product-img'>
      <button class='bag-btn' data-id='1'>
            <i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>
            add to cart
          </button>

    </div>
    <h3>Blackberry Bomb</h3>
    <h4>$3/roll</h4>
  </article>


  <article class="product">
    <div class='img-container'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x700" alt="product" class='product-img'>
      <button class='bag-btn' data-id='1'>
            <i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>
            add to cart
          </button>

    </div>
    <h3>Blackberry Bomb</h3>
    <h4>$3/roll</h4>
  </article>

  <article class="product">
    <div class='img-container'>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x500" alt="product" class='product-img'>
      <button class='bag-btn' data-id='1'>
            <i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>
            add to cart
          </button>

    </div>
    <h3>Blackberry Bomb</h3>
    <h4>$3/roll</h4>
  </article>


  <!-- end of single product -->
</div>
```